# you tried everything but Microsoft Office Word still can't open .asd file

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, autosave

All the solutions will tell you that the recovery file *.asd can be open by Microsoft office word, for some reasons mine didn't open, i tried every solution and it didn't work, it always says :

```
Microsoft Office Word can't open this file bla bla bla...
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what every solution you tried was. It looks pretty simple to open a word auto saved document: http://tompai.pro/computers/solved-open-asd-file-with-word/

Comment: By the way, you can't just say, "I tried every solution and it didn't work." Logic says there is no point in posting your question here if you've already tried everything - because then there is no solution.

Comment: @Appleoddity how are you doing ?

Answer (score 2):

So this is no **pretty solution**, but if you are desperate this could save you a bit of your work (it did for me), at least you recover some of the text.

the solution is to open notepad and than drag and drop the ASD file into it, of corse the DocX file isn't just ASCII text, but it contains some of the text you had been writing in your document, So you can recover it, sadly the images and tables can't be recovered, but it's better than nothing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but LibreOffice opened an ASD document that Word wouldn't touch. It lost a lot of formatting and pictures, but I recovered the majority of my daughter's work.